# Core Text occasionally fails to produce results [iOS]

Tags: ios, core-text

I’m helping out a company with a project for iOS, which is using Core Text. Some users of the app have reported that text is occasionally missing from within the app. It seems™ that this is somewhat memory related, because it’s solvable by shutting down the app along with background apps.

I made a few lines of code which simulates the use of the app – so the app “runs itself”, navigating between view controllers randomly, scrolling in text fields etc – to track if this issue occurs by normal use.

I’ve found some memory leaks related to the use of Core Text, but according to instruments the amount of memory lost is quite low. However, when the simulation has been running for about 20 minutes or so, the app is shut down by the os because of memory warnings.

I’m intending to fix this memory leaks, but my problem is that I will not be able to ensure that this fixes the main bug (missing text), since I cannot reproduce it myself.

So my final question is: have anyone experienced issues with missing text on iOS while using Core Text, which are due to leaked memory? Does it sound plausible? If so, is this related to only specific versions of iOS?

I appreciate any answers that can help me out!

Answer (score 1):

UIViewControllers may implement didReceiveMemoryWarning that the system calls when your app is on low memory. Framework classes, as core text, are most likely do implement this and act accordingly to save memory. So it is possible that your core text object aims to help your app resolving the low-mem situation with freeing some of its resources that can even cause it to blank its contents. Fix first *all* memory leaks in your app.

On the other hand, all bugs are very difficult to correct if you can't reproduce them. If you suspect that the issue is due to low memory, try to simulate this yourself by allocating huge amount of memory in your application and hope that you can reproduce the erroneous behavior that way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It’s rather odd, I think. If these leaks cause the issue for some users, why would it be that the app does not crash for them (but the text is blank), yet it does for me (and I never see the blank text)? Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know exactly how the memory management of iOS work, but I can imagine such a scenario:
 1) Your app is consuming "too much" memory. The OS sends the notifications to your app / UIViewControllers
 2) UIViewControllers of the fw reduces their mem footprint for example freeing some UI resources (blank text view)
 3) you still consume too much memory
 4) if there are no other apps running, the OS could even leave your app running
 5) if there are other apps that need memory, the OS can consider to make a more radical step and kill your process

Comment: So it depends on the situation, like other apps loaded, what is the flexibility of the OS between the memory warning and the kill signal, how much memory you free after the first warning, etc.

Comment: Yes, I assume that the complex nature of memory management of iOS may create very different scenarios on my device and other users’ devices. I guess the best approach is to fix the memory leaks and then just hope for the best that it also fixes the missing text issue. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: You can "thank" my answer by accepting it clicking on the tick and voting it up clicking on the up arrow :) Hope you'll find the cause of your troubles, non-reproducible or non-deterministic bugs are among the ugliest things in sw development.